# NSMutableArray that calls local html

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to change one of the tutorials Sam's teach yourself iOs in 24 hours.
In this example, a tableview is loaded with an NSMutableArray that defines various external URLs.
How can I modify this bit of the code to call local html files instead of the external URLs?
Thanks in advance.

```
(void)createFlowerData {

    NSMutableArray *redFlowers;
    NSMutableArray *blueFlowers;

    _flowerSections=@[@"Red Flowers",@"Blue Flowers"];

    redFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    blueFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Poppy",
                            @"picture":@"Poppy.png",

    [blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Hyacinth",
                            @"picture":@"Hyacinth.png",
                            @"url":@"http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_(flower)"}];

    _flowerData=@[redFlowers,blueFlowers];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by local file you mean a file included in the project resources or application bundle. This is the code which will get you the path for local html (lets say `sample.html`)

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
```

Now you want to replace this in the array.

```
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Hyacinth",
                        @"picture":@"Hyacinth.png",
                        @"url":htmlPath];
```

Rest I assume is already taken care by the sample code your are referring. If not you need to study the code and modify accordingly.

Hope that helps!